# is it possible to use 2 different scripts under 1 button?

Tags: autohotkey, mouse, send

What commands should be used to make scripts work under 1 button?
I'm talking about exactly

Press Lbutton sending :

```
                  ~f::
                  Send, {p down}
                  KeyWait f  
                  Send, {p up}
                  sleep, 899
                  Send, %var%
                  return
```

press Lbutton again sending:

```
                  ~2::
                  Send, {o down}
                  KeyWait 2  
                  Send, {o up}
                  Send, %var%
                  sleep, 899
                  Send, %var%}
                  return
```

and 3rd click goes back to the beginning.

I expect help, idea or answer is it possible at all?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is pretty unclear and I'm having a hard time understanding what you want the script to do. I'll post a solution solving what I currently think you are asking for, but please feel free to clarify if it's not quite what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Using a basic `if` statement.

```
mState := 0

~LButton::
    if(mState = 0)
    {
        Send, {p down}
        Send, {p up}
        sleep, 899
        Send, %var%
    }
    else
    {
        Send, {o down}
        Send, {o up}
        Send, %var%
        sleep, 899
        Send, %var%
    }

    mState := !mState

    return
```

In the future, please at least try to show what work you've done to try to solve the problem yourself. It makes it a lot easier for people answering these questions to figure out what you want the program to do and to adjust the code accordingly.